# Pjax not working with Laravel4

Tags: laravel, pjax

I'm trying to setup Pjax in Laravel 4 project but I always get empty response from the server.
In fact response is getting aborted and I don't see any response. Looks like Laravel is not handling the request. I wonder if it is because of Headers set by Pjax.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. It was because of 650ms timeout set in jquery.pjax.js.
I removed it and now it works fine.